# Rotation and Transformation in Codenameone

Tags: rotation, transformation, codenameone

I was working on a project in codenameone. 
I had couple of questions regarding transformations,
1. What is the Alternative to graphics.transform in codenameone?
2. I am performing a rotation of an object, but I want to set the circumference or the radius of the rotations as that rotation radius is more than the size of the object. 
I Am some what struck. I do not know how to set radius of the rotation . 
I have a Circle object and I want another object like a rectangle to rotate on surface of the circle with a rotation radius same as that of size of the rectangle. Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Codename One graphics has its own transform operations very similar to the Java2D set of transform operations. Notice that these are in the graphics drawing layer and don't apply to the component layer so if you are referring to an FX like transform node this isn't something that makes sense for Codename One.

It can be achieved in Codename One since you can override the paint and just set the transform before the paint and restore it after. This can work for some cases but notice that some complex things e.g. text input might fail in such cases.

Comment: Everything is working fine!! Am resetting the transform after applying transformation to objects. But when I want another object to rotate at the corner of a circle, it is rotating but it is rotating with more width height than the original object

Comment: Are you using the transform version that accepts a pivot point? Keep in mind that components are positioned within their parent container so they are not at 0,0 but rather at getX()/getY()